# Meaning of Ghataka Shruti

Tags: philosophy, terminology, vishishtadvaita

Advaita follows Abheda Shruti, Dvaita Bheda Shruti. Vishishtadvaita follows Ghataka Shruti.

Abheda Shruti means passages from Shruti literature which talk about non-difference. Bheda Shruti means passages which talk about difference between Jivatma and Paramatma. 
What does Ghataka mean in this sense?

Comment: Dvaita is wrong connutation and its tattvada, this takes abheda vachanna and conveys the hidden meaning, and takes them in correct prespective tattvada doesnt ignore abheda.. where as advita does ignore the bheda shruti as aparrent..

Answer (score 3):

Upanishads have multiple teachings - some say Atman and Brahman are same and some they are completely different. Visish Advaitha reconciles both using Ghataka Shruti. It uses portion of Upanishads saying Brahman is the inner controller (Antaryami) present inside all Chit and Achit elements of Brahman. We can say like Trees have various fruits but are different from it yet live in tree. In same way, Atman resides in the body of Brahman. The whole world is Brahman and it controls us from inside.

### Examples of Abheda Shruti (Oneness of Atman and Brahman)

This self was indeed brahman in the beginning. It knew only I as 'I am Brahmaṇ' (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10)

That which is the subtlest of all is the Self of all this. It is the Truth. It is the Self. That thou art, O Śvetaketu. (Chandogya Upanishad 6.8.7)

### Example of Bheda Shruti (Difference between Atman and Brahman)

In this infinite wheel of Brahman, in which everything lives and rests, the pilgrim soul is whirled about. Knowing the individual soul, hitherto regarded as separate, to be itself the Moving Force, and blessed by Him, it attains immortality. (Svetasvatara
Upanishad 1.6)

### Example of Ghakata Shruti (Reconciliation of both views)

He who inhabits the earth but is within it, whom the earth does not know, **whose body is the earth, and who controls the earth from within**, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self.(Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 3.7.3)

Comment: Can you add views of some āchāryas on how they have defined the 'ghaṭaka śruti' and other types? That'll make the answer more definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing meaning of 'Ghataka Shruti' as defined in [wisdom library](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ghataka):

> Ghaṭaka (घटक) refers to category of declaration on Brahman and
>   Ātman.—**Ghaṭaka-śruti refers to those affirming identity between Atman
>   and Brahman**.

I hope this is what you are seeking.

Comment: The OP is asking literal meaning of Ghataka Shruti. He added already that Vishishtadvaitans follow Ghataka Shruti.  "Why is it called Ghataka shruti" is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Namaskaram. I want to try answering. Ghataka Sruthi as told earlier is reconciling. Ghataka literally means earthen pot. The pot is created from soil. It looks it is different from soil.though it takes all qualities of soil,due to the process the pot acquires its own identity. And looks different from soil. So one sees pot and soil seperate. But when the same pot is broken ,it gets united into the soil leaving it's identity of pot. No one further calls it as pot but say it merged into soil. Same way jeevatma though looks different from paramatma,has quality of its own still it is un detachable from paramatma. So visistaadwaitam says jeevatma are body of paramathma,and by doing our nitya karma we are doing kainkaryam to paramathma.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).